# django error while installing

Tags: python, django

Getting error while installing Django

```
C:\Users\Lenovo>pip install django
Collecting django
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03DBE3B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03DBE330>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03DBE350>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03DBE2D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03DBE210>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))': /simple/django/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django
```

Comment: It looks like you have a network connection issue ('Cannot connect to proxy.'). Check your internet connection settings first.

Answer (score 0):

Set proxies and check your network connection:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://<<your_proxy>>:<<your_port>>
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://<<your_proxy>>:<<your_port>>
```